# HTML5 role=main, how to style

Tags: css, html

If I have

```
<div role="main">

</div>
```

How do I style `main` with CSS? Or do I also have to add an ID or a class to the `<div>`?

Comment: Would you please accept the answer to this question

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend adding an ID or class. It's the most cross-browser and efficient way.

If you can't do this, then you'll need to use an attribute selector:

```
div[role="main"]
```

Comment: You can use http://selectivizr.com/ to polyfill support into IE6-8 for the attribute selector.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: IE 7 and 8 both support the attribute selector, though; it’s CSS2! Polyfilling this works for IE 6, but I hope people consider at length whether they really want to support that.